Projective closure of affine parametrized curve is just projective parametrization
In class I have seen this statement being used implicitly:

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $p: \mathbb{A}^1(k) \to \mathbb{A}^n(k)$ be a parametrization of a curve given by polynomials; that is, $p = \langle p_1, \ldots, p_n \rangle$ where $p_i \in k[T]$. Let $C = \mathrm{Im}\ p = \{(p_1(t),\ldots,p_n(t)) \mid t \in k\}$.
Assume $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$ (with the Zariski topology).*
Under the identification of $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$ with $U_0 = \{[1: x_1 : \cdots : x_n] \mid x_i \in k\} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n(k)$, we have that:
$$ \mathrm{cl}_{\mathbb{P}^n(k)}(C) = \{[a^d : a^d p_1(b/a) : \cdots : a^d p_n(b/a)] \mid [a : b] \in \mathbb{P}^1(k)\} $$
where $d$ is high enough to kill the denominator in all of the $p_i(b/a)$.
In other words, $ \mathrm{cl}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(C) = \mathrm{Im}\ \tilde{p}$ where $\tilde{p}: \mathbb{P}^1(k) \to \mathbb{P}^n(k)$ is defined by $[a : b] \mapsto [a^d : a^d p_1(b/a) : \cdots : a^d p_n(b/a)]$.
* I think this is automatic, but in any case just assume it's true.

A slogan for this statement could be "in order to obtain the projective closure of a parametrized affine curve, it suffices to extend the parametrization to the entire projective line" (i.e. just add the point at infinity as a parameter value).
I have been told this follows from the following fact:

If $I$ is the ideal associated to an algebraic affine set $X$, then the ideal associated to the projective closure of $X$ is generated by the homogeneization of each element of $I$.

I don't see how one is directly related to the other, because the latter is talking about the associated ideal but in the original problem we're using the parametrizations directly.

My attempt at proving the statement directly:
First observe that, using the same notation and identification as above, we have:
$$C = \{(p_1(t),\ldots,p_n(t)) \mid t \in k\} = \{(p_1(b/a),\ldots,p_n(b/a)) \mid [a:b] \in \mathbb{P}^1(k),\ a \ne 0\} = \tilde{p}[\mathbb{P}^1(k) \smallsetminus \{[0 : 1]\}]$$
In the end we want to prove
$\mathrm{cl}_{\mathbb{P}^n(k)}(C) = \tilde{p}[\mathbb{P}^1(k)]$. Since $\mathrm{cl}_{\mathbb{P}^1(k)}(\mathbb{P}^1(k) \smallsetminus \{[0 : 1]\}) = \mathbb{P}^1(k)$, using this fact it suffices to prove that $\tilde{p}[\mathbb{P}^1(k)]$ is closed. I think we can apply Are sets given in parametric form always algebraic? to prove this.
But I don't know if this proof works and the proofs in the linked question use some machinery I'm not entirely comfortable with yet.
